# Animations and animation delay behaving randomly on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, animation, browser, safari

I am trying to animate a certain page where there are three main components, two tables and one chart.
Please refer the JSFiddle to replicate the same on your Safari browser.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhwanilshah/gfyzh3am/)

Two rows of the first table are shown one after the another i.e. the green row slides in then slides out cueing the yellow row to slide in. After a couple of seconds the yellow row slides out and then green comes back. After green comes back to the original position.

Two divs below slide in simultaneously. Now, what is happening is I make the green row absolute after it slides out so that the yellow row shifts up on the same position but on Safari, the 'position: absolute' in the green row is not applying.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideRightDisappear {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    99% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        position: absolute;
    }
}

@keyframes slideRightDisappear {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    99% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

The yellow row also when slides out does not take absolute position to pull the lower two division up.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeftDisappear {
    0% {
        display: inline;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes slideLeftDisappear {
    0% {
        display: inline;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Also, the two divisions at the bottom do not animate and just suddenly appear.

Check the fiddle on Chrome, that is how ideally it should work and then check it on Safari for the main issue.

Do not be confused by the way I am injecting the animation, my requirement is that I want to chain multiple animations and start and stop them on demand so what I do is, I pass a list of animation properties and join them individually and add it to the DOM style. I was earlier concatenating the shorthand but apparently Safari does not consider the shorthand so I went further and split each animation into its properties.

Also, one more issue which I am not able to replicate is when I click on the animate button, all my animations run simultaneously ignoring the delay that I give.

```js
function animator () {
  addAnimationToElement('row-1', ['fadeInLeftBig', 'slideRightDisappear', 'slideLeftAppear'], ['0.5s', '0.3s', '0.5s'], ['linear', 'linear', 'linear'], ['0.6s', '3s', '7.5s'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['normal', 'normal', 'normal'], ['forwards', 'forwards', 'forwards'], ['running', 'running', 'running'])

addAnimationToElement('row-2', ['slideInLeft', 'slideLeftDisappear'], ['0.5s', '0.5s'], ['linear', 'linear'], ['4s', '6.5s'], ['1', '1'], ['normal', 'normal'], ['forwards', 'forwards'], ['running', 'running'])

addAnimationToElement('table', ['fadeInLeftBig'], ['1.5s'], ['cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)'], ['9s'], ['1'], ['normal'], ['forwards'], ['running'])

addAnimationToElement('chart', ['fadeInRightBig'], ['1.5s'], ['cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)'], ['9s'], ['1'], ['normal'], ['forwards'], ['running'])
  
}

function pause () {
 document.getElementById('portfolio').style.opacity = 0;
}


function addAnimationToElement (elementID, animationName, animationDuration, animationTimingFunction, animationDelay, animationIterationCount, animationDirection, animationFillMode, animationPlayState) {
      // Animation for Safari
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationName = animationName.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationDuration = animationDuration.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationTimingFunction = animationTimingFunction.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationDelay = animationDelay.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationIterationCount = animationIterationCount.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationDirection = animationDirection.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationFillMode = animationFillMode.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = animationPlayState.join(', ')
      // Animation for other browsers
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationName = animationName.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationDuration = animationDuration.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationTimingFunction = animationTimingFunction.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationDelay = animationDelay.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationIterationCount = animationIterationCount.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationDirection = animationDirection.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationFillMode = animationFillMode.join(', ')
      document.getElementById(elementID).style.animationPlayState = animationPlayState.join(', ')
    }
```

```css
.transparent_element {
 opacity: 0;
}

#row-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}

#row-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#table {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#chart {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slideLeftAppear {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0,);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@keyframes slideLeftAppear {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRightDisappear {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 99% {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 }
 100% {
  position: absolute;
 }
}

@keyframes slideRightDisappear {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 99% {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 }
 100% {
  position: absolute;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRightBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(400px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(400px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRightBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(400px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(400px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeftDisappear {
 0% {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 99% {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
 100% {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@keyframes slideLeftDisappear {
 0% {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 99% {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
 100% {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<div>

<button onclick="animator()">
Animate
</button>
<button onclick="pause()">
Pause
</button>
<table>
<tr id="row-1" class="transparent_element" style="-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 4px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); -moz-box-shadow: 6px 4px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); box-shadow: 6px 4px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);  height: 90px;">
  </tr>
<tr id="row-2" class="transparent_element" style="-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 4px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); -moz-box-shadow: 6px 4px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); box-shadow: 6px 4px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);  height: 90px;">
  </tr>          
</table>

<div id="table" class="transparent_element"></div>
<div id="chart" class="transparent_element"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For me your code in Chrome and in Safari behave the same.

Comment: Are you sure about this implementing? I would do job this way: write styles for example `slideLeftDisappear` or `slideAppear` and add this to block when button is pressed. Smth like this.

Comment: @Vadim Are you saying it is working as I described it should or you are facing the same issue on both the browser. I checked just now and for me the Chrome and Safari output are completely different.

Comment: @Vadim Could you elaborate on what you mean by when you say 'write style and add this to the block'. I am pretty sure the Javascript is working because I have been using this way for quite some time now. But if you could suggest a better approach that would be wonderful.

Comment: @Vadim If you can, just check the fiddle, I have updated it a bit. Instead of using JS to induce the animation. I am using classes and doing it. This actually reproduces my other error which I am facing i.e. the animation delay is ignored and all the elements just show up immediately.

Comment: Sorry, @Dhwanil, but now I can't write write code. To be clenear: write CSS class, which name you add to class name list of block when button is pressed. DOM API have some methods like `element.classList.add()` and 'element.classList.remove()', where is `element = document.querySelector('.box')`

Comment: @Vadim I know about the DOM APIs to manipulate the class but my main issue is that the values for the delays will change every time my page loads due to some dynamic content. So, to keep up with that I use JS to inject the values directly. I will try to create classes dynamically and inject them. Maybe that should work. Thank you!

Comment: @Vadim I tried your way as well, I am dynamically making classes with the delay and name and appending that class. Check the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/dhwanilshah/yc8hd7s9/